# Minifier that preserves conditional comments?

Tags: javascript, minify

I tried out the online [JS Minifier](http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html) but it cuts out conditional comments like:

```
 var u = navigator.userAgent;var e=/*@cc_on!@*/false;

                           BECOMES

 var u=navigator.userAgent;var e=false;
```

This would affect the operation of the code, so instead of manually adding the stripped out comments manually, I'm looking for a minifier that intelligently preserves these and any such comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUICompressor reportedly does the needful. Here is an excerpt from a blog:

...
But fret not, it’s not as bad as you think. Unfortunately, JSMin removes conditional compilation comments, but I believe this is due to not having been updated in a while, and not up to speed with modern web development practices.

Using other tools such as *YUI compressor* or packer does indeed work fine with conditional compilation. 
...

You can read the entire post at http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/26/conditional-compilation-in-javascript/

Comment: Note however that although YUI compressor will retain conditional comments, the presence of said comments will automatically reduce the level of compression such that variable names are no longer shortened/obfuscated. It has to do this because the comments themselves may refer to variables in scope, much like eval could. See http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/22/

Comment: Packer http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ works great for me, and it has variable name shortening too (optional).

Answer (score 0):

There's also [a .NET port of YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) which allows you to:-

- intergrate the minification/file combining into Visual Studio post-build events
- intergrate into a TFS Build (including CI)
- if you wish to just use the dll's in your own code (eg. on the fly minification).

because this is a port of the (original) java version YUI Compressor, which Vinnie and Crescentfresh mention above, it should give you the same results BUT all in the .NET environment -- no need for java.

HTH.